# Is 'smth' a correct abbreviation in American English?

Tags: american-english, abbreviations

How common is the usage of 'smth' in American English as an abbreviation of 'something'?

Comment: Typical, no; but I do recognize "smth" as "something".  It is more like Twitter code than American English.

Comment: Do you have in examples in context so that we can tell what you're talking about (it's not obvious)?

Comment: for instance : 'Do smth about his behavior!'

Comment: @lukas I would not recognize your example.  It looks erroneous to me.

Comment: I am wondering, why so many people have given me negative points?

Comment: I'm not sure about the downvotes either. It doesn't show any research but otherwise I think the question itself is valid because even though I disagree with the term's use, I've seen it more and more lately so an explanation of correctness and usage is useful.

Comment: I've only seen it here.  Seems to me to be an invention of the authors of ESL tests.

Comment: Writers can abbreviate as they like. No noun has a "regular abbreviation". That said, nouns are often abbreviated leaving out all the syllables. So, "smthg" would follow that pattern.

Comment: It sounds as if someone has objected to your using "smth". In anything but the most informal contexts, i.e. in which nobody bothers much about English, "smth" is not an accepted abbreviation. The sole exception seems to be dictionaries in which many words are reduced for space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Neither *smth* nor *sth* is a standard abbreviation in American English.

The first looks like *Smith,* which there’s surely no reason to abbreviate. *Smithying,* perhaps. The second looks like *south*, the direction. It also reminds me of my friend *Seth,* or perhaps in the right context the *Sith* from *Star Wars.*

So while I’m sure it means something, I can’t quite say what, and it’s a burden, even an imposition, on your readers to make them try to do so. I strongly advise against using *sth* to mean anything at all.  Just type the thing out that you actually mean.

---

Nthr *smth* nr *sth* z a stndrd abrvshn n Amrcn Nglsh.

Th 1st lks lk *Smth*, whch thr’s shrly no rsn 2 abrvt. Smthyng, prhps. Th 2nd lks lk sth, th drcshn. It also rmndz me v my frnd *Sth*, o prhps n th rt cntxt th *Sth* frm *Str Wrz*.

So whl I’m shr it mnz smthng, I cn’t qt sy wht, & itz a brdn, evn an unknd impsshn, on yr rdrz 2 mk thm try 2 do so. I strngly advs agnst usng *sth* 2 mn anythng @ al. Jst typ th thng owt tht U actly mn.

Comment: Same goes for UK English: it looks really strange to see sth, smth and smby in normal text when everything else is written in full. It seems to be most common from Indian writers.

Comment: In technical semantic descriptions, _something_ is often abbreviated to s.t, and _someone_ to s.o. For instance, one might [gloss the Ojibwe verb](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Rhodes-Lawler-1981-cls17.pdf) _miijgaazod_ as 'to be given s.t."

Comment: @Hugo I have a little program that does that. Send me mail if you’d like a copy.

Answer (score 7):

*Smth* is not used to my knowledge as a standard abbreviation, but I have seen *sb* for ‘somebody’ and *sth* for ‘something’ in idiom dictionaries such as the [Oxford Idioms Dictionary](http://amzn.com/0194317234) and [McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Idioms](http://amzn.com/0071478930).

Comment: Short and to the point, thank you. I don't see why ELU shouldn't enthusiastically adopt *sth/sb* along with *OP* and *TL;DR*. These four "less than universal" abbreviations are exceptionally useful for posters here, and I doubt there are even half-a-dozen others remotely in the same league. I'm unfamiliar with at least half the [standard elu abbreviations](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/147), and that has never bothered me. But these two are in constant use.

Comment: I've seen it in bilingual dictionaries, although it seems less common online (where there's more space).

Answer (score 1):

In Taiwan, to teach verbs, smth and smb are used to shorten the explanation or definition. It's quite common here.

Comment: +1 Please cite a reputable source that confirms your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In English schoolbooks for German students, I think you can find the abbreviation s.b. and sth. I'm not sure about the second one, but if somebody (s.b.) cares, you can look it up in the vocabulary section in those books.

Comment: Hi Tommy, welcome to English Language & Usage. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference or other evidence. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: Note also that proper nouns are capitalised. I've deleted the bit at the end: "good luck" or "thank you" messages are unnecessary and distract from the question. Some might also query the words after "second one" but I've left them in *purely as an example of how the abbreviation is used.*

Comment: Lastly, note that the OP asks about *American English*, which your answer doesn't address; it would therefore be more suited as a *comment*. You can add comments once you earn more "reputation" - for more about this, take the **[Tour]** of the site (I can recommend it!). :-)

Answer (score -3):

Well this sure aged well, didn't it?

Sth, smth, and the less frequently used stg and smtg are all written abbreviations for "something."  They are not particularly common abbreviations.  This word is generally inappropriate for a formal scholarly document due to ambiguity.  The word is much more suited to dialogue, which is where you would typically find it: in informal conversations and internet forum posts.

There seem to be a lot of gatekeepers to the English language here.  I hate to have to be the one to pop the collective thought bubble, but the language developed before it was "standardized."  It continues to develop and it doesn't really care about the rules we say it should follow.
As custodians of the language, our responsibility is not to say "Not in MY English," but to monitor how the language grows and changes.  One of those recent developments has been that many more people use writing to communicate much more frequently than ever before in history.  That's in itself a beautiful thing, but rather than saying "people are using my English wrong on the internet," it would be more constructive to try to determine and document what rules they Are using.

Source:  I bin writin' n' speakin' 'mer'can English fer like 35 years out here.

You might call it a layman's perspective, but I call it closer to "real American English" than anything you'll learn in a textbook.

Comment: Answers unaccompanied by supporting research, credible references, are considered inadequate on ELU, kyler. They tend to come across as (and may be little more than) personal opinion or the result of parochial exposure to usage. // And while usage certainly drives acceptability in English, rejecting subjective views and poor sampling are what the gatekeepers are intended to do. Hence the collective approach: much safer than assuming every contributor is Chomsky's grandson.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420055)